# Why can't figma detach the master component? Is there a philosophy behind it?

Tags: figma

I know figma can detach instance.

But, Why can't figma detach the master component?

What's the background or any figma's philosophy ?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of detaching, only applies to component instances. You want to detach the component instance from its Master Component, so that any future change you make to its ex-Master Component won't apply to the detached instance anymore.

But why is there no "Detach" command for the Master Component itself? Since the Master Component is a top level template for component instance, it has no dependent, and therefore, there is no parent it could detach from.

ANALOGY:

1. You can delete files from a hard drive using Windows Explorer.
2. But you cannot "delete" a hard drive from Windows Explorer.

If you still want more details about this, check this article: https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/can-you-detach-master-component-figma/